# INSERT INTO only if dataset doesn't already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, duplicates

I have this script in my program. It inserts new datasets for every entry in `user_settings` into my `pricelist` table. It works fine.

```
INSERT INTO [pricelist]
       ([ID]
       ,[plf]
       ,[vdf]
       ,[vdt]
       ,[plID]
       ,[usID])
 SELECT
       NEWID()
       ,5.5
       ,'2017-01-02 00:00:00'
       ,'2027-01-03 00:00:00'
       ,'8020F2FA1C80XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
       ,ID
FROM [user_settings]
```

But if I need to re-run the script, in case run 1 canceled for any reason. I get duplicate entries in table `pricelist`. How can I avoid this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using ? You can avoid this by creating unique constraint

Comment: @prdp `[]` and  `NEWID()` say `MSQL`

Comment: SQL Management Studio

Comment: Perform a select first and insert if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Tell your unique combination in `pricelist` table

Comment: why not have a unique index? let the database force this for you.

Comment: no constraints in `pricelist` table

Comment: @user1673665 - I didn't ask for constraint. How are saying the data is duplicated ? In which column/columns data is duplicated ?

Comment: it creates a duplicate dataset with the same information but different id

Answer (score 1):

You should consider adding a `unique constraint` on your table to avoid such problems.

Use `NOT Exists` to avoid inserting duplicate data. Based on your comments, you need to check for all the columns except the `ID`

```
INSERT INTO [pricelist]
            ([ID],[plf],[vdf],[vdt],[plID],[usID])
SELECT [ID],[plf],[vdf],[vdt],[plID],[usID]
FROM   (SELECT Newid()                       ID,
               5.5                           AS plf,
               '2017-01-02 00:00:00'         AS vdf,
               '2027-01-03 00:00:00'         AS vdt,
               '8020F2FA1C80XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' AS plID,
               ID                            AS usID
        FROM   [user_settings]) u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   pricelist p
                   WHERE  u.plf = p.plf
                          AND u.vdf = p.vdf
                          AND u.vdt = p.vdt
                          AND u.plID = p.plID
                          AND u.usID = p.usID)
```

Comment: ok thank you I've got a sproblem with syntax but I think this was caused by some edits I made. So I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
 INSERT INTO [pricelist]
        SELECT NEWID(), u.*
        FROM [user_settings] u
        LEFT JOIN [pricelist] p
          ON u.[id] = p.[id]
        WHERE p.[id] IS NULL
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to make your answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO [pricelist]
       ([ID]
       ,[plf]
       ,[vdf]
       ,[vdt]
       ,[plID]
       ,[usID])
 SELECT
       NEWID()
       ,5.5
       ,'2017-01-02 00:00:00'
       ,'2027-01-03 00:00:00'
       ,'8020F2FA1C80XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
       ,ID
FROM [user_settings] AS us
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [pricelist] AS p WHERE p.UsID = us.ID);
```

Although, this is not thread safe, and you might still end up with duplicates if you meet a race condition. If something should be unique, then give it a unique constraint, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE PriceList ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_PriceList__usID UNIQUE (usID);
```

This will guarantee no duplicates. The most threadsafe `INSERT` I know of is to use `MERGE WITH (HOLDLOCK)`:

```
MERGE [PriceList] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS p
USING [user_settings]  AS US
    ON us.ID = p.usID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ([ID], [plf], [vdf], [vdt], [plID], [usID])
    VALUES (NEWID(), 5.5, '2017-01-02 00:00:00', '2027-01-03 00:00:00', 
            '8020F2FA1C80XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', us.[ID]);
```

This is still no substitute for creating your constraint though.

*N.B. It is not quite clear from your question how you define a duplicate, for brevity I have assumed it is just `usID` in the table, but if it is more columns, all of the principles outlined above still apply*

**ADDENDUM**

If the above is not working, then you may need to add more conditions to your join to include more columns:

```
MERGE PriceList WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS p
USING 
(   SELECT  ID = NEWID(), 
            plf = 5.5, 
            vdf = '2017-01-02 00:00:00', 
            vdt = '2027-01-03 00:00:00',
            plID = '8020F2FA1C80XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            usID = us.ID
    FROM    user_settings  AS us
    GROUP BY us.ID -- only needed if us.ID is not unique
) AS us
    ON us.usID = p.usID
    AND us.plf = p.plf
    AND us.vdf = p.vdf
    AND us.vdt = p.vdt
    AND us.plID = p.plID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (ID, plf, vdf, vdt, plID, usID)
    VALUES (us.ID, us.plf, us.vdf, us.vdt, us.plID, us.usID);
```

Finally, part of the problem could be existing duplicates, which you can remove using something like:

```
DELETE  t
FROM    (   SELECT  *, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY plf, vdf, vdt, plID, usID ORDER BY ID)
            FROM    PriceList
        ) AS t
WHERE   t.RowNumber > 1;
```

Comment: after running the script a second time there exist 2 rows in whose every column content is the same except of primary key column ID.

Comment: Which columns define a duplicate? Is `ID` unique in `user_settings`?